# How Does a Disparity in Number of Documents (Training Data Points) Affect Text Classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, svm, scikit-learn

I have collected a fairly clean set of data (5,410 documents) to train a text classifier.  I am now attempting to improve my classification success.  (Note: When I trained/tested the classifier from in-sample data, I scored really well.  Now that I'm using out-of-sample data, my success is down about 25%.  Bad news, but not unexpected for a total ML newb.)

Does having an equal (or more equal) distribution of training documents improve classification success?  For instance, although I have only six categories -- Labels A,B,C,D,E, F -- the number of training docs I have for each label varies widely, as Label A = 328; Label B = 1,973; Label C = 148; Label D = 822; Label E = 40; and Label F = 1,242.  Any thoughts??  (Note: I don't actually know if this is a representative distribution of what I'm likely to to see out of sample. Is there an ideal algorithm to help with this uncertainty?)

Presently I am using Scikit's `svm.LinearSVC()` to classify.  Thank you for any insight!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can affect the classification in a dramatic way. You can use this parameter from the scikit-learn LinearSVC documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) to compensate the imbalance.

```
class_weight : {dict, ‘balanced’}, optional
```

Set the parameter C of class i to class_weight[i]*C for SVC. If not given, all classes are supposed to have weight one. The “balanced” mode uses the values of y to automatically adjust weights inversely proportional to class frequencies in the input data as `n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y))`